# ElasticSearch constraints when fetching more than 50k documents using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am querying elasticsearch index using java api `SearchSourceBuilder`. Am having more than `100k` documents in my index and i have increased `index.max_result_window` to `120000` and then from my java code if i try to fetch `120k` documents. It throws null pointer exception in the below line.

```
SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
```

If i reduced the size of `SearchSourceBuilder` to `50k` then its working properly, but i have able to fetch only `50k` documents.

Please find my code below :

```
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
    Document doc=new Document();

    logger.info("Started Indexing the Document.....");

    try {
        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
    searchRequest.types(TYPE);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
    searchSourceBuilder.size(120000); 
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
         searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits(); /// Getting null pointer exception after porcessing some documents. Count is not very constant.
    long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
    logger.info("Total Hits --->"+totalHits);
```

Please find my index setting details

```
{
  "document_attachment": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "document_attachment",
        "max_result_window": "150000",
        "creation_date": "1531402811016",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "custom_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            },
            "product_catalog_keywords_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "UBRQAkg-Su-FfeAtBTGFIw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020399"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a scrolling search instead of trying to get everything all at once. This allows you to page through the results.

With scrolling you can get as many results as you need; there's no upper limit.You won't be able to get ranked results t, but that is kind of meaningless on result sets this big.

See [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search-scroll.html) on how to do this.